# XPath query is not working properly with special character

Tags: php, xml, dom, search, xpath

I use the following Xpath to search for a keyword, but when I use "@" in `$search` the query is not working.

```
 $findword= 'Find @ replace';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    preg_match("/$findword/i", $findResultRow['Description'],$matches);
    $dom->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding(strtolower($findResultRow['Description']), 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $search = strtolower($findword);
    foreach($xpath->query("(//*[contains(text(), $search)])[1]") as $node)
    {
    $desc=$findResultRow['Description'];
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue. Could you please provide your XML data? However, it looks weird how you pass in your search value, I would expect you to do something like `$xpath->query("(//*[contains(text(), " . $search . ")])[1]")` in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for a literal string then you need

```
foreach($xpath->query("(//*[contains(text(), '$search')])[1]") as $node)
```

that way, the PHP variable has a string value like `foo@example.com` the XPath expression will be `//*[contains(text(), 'foo@example.com')]`.